# The most efficient way to get algorithm complexity table

Tags: r, algorithm, time-complexity

I was trying to fill in the table which is given as an exercise problem in the "Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd ed"(published by The MIT Press)(page. 14) with R.

[Click this link to see the table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLJuq.png)

// below : Added Sentence, thanks to G. Bach's comment.

I was supposed to fill in the cells with the

*largest size n of a problem that can be solved in time t, assuming that the algorithm to solve the problem takes f(n) microseconds.*

// above : Added Sentence, thanks to G. Bach's comment.

My code is just like below.

```
msec <- 1
sec <- msec * 1000000
min <- sec * 60
hour <- min * 60
day <- hour * 24
mon <- day * 30
year <- day * 365
cen <- year * 100

time_units = c( sec, min, hour, day, mon, year, cen )

time_funcs = list(
    lg_n = function(x) 2^x,
    sqrt_2 = function(x) x^2,
    itself = function(x) x,
    n_sq = function(x) sqrt(x),
    n_3sq = function(x) pracma::nthroot(x, 3),
    nsq_of_2 = function(x) log2(x)
)

obvious_vals <- sapply( time_units, plyr::each(time_funcs) )
```

The content of 'obvious_vals' is

```
                 [,1]         [,2]         [,3]         [,4]         [,5]         [,6]         [,7]
lg_n              Inf          Inf          Inf          Inf          Inf          Inf          Inf
sqrt_2   1.000000e+12 3.600000e+15 1.296000e+19 7.464960e+21 6.718464e+24 9.945193e+26 9.945193e+30
itself   1.000000e+06 6.000000e+07 3.600000e+09 8.640000e+10 2.592000e+12 3.153600e+13 3.153600e+15
n_sq     1.000000e+03 7.745967e+03 6.000000e+04 2.939388e+05 1.609969e+06 5.615692e+06 5.615692e+07
n_3sq    1.000000e+02 3.914868e+02 1.532619e+03 4.420838e+03 1.373657e+04 3.159382e+04 1.466455e+05
nsq_of_2 1.993157e+01 2.583846e+01 3.174535e+01 3.633031e+01 4.123720e+01 4.484206e+01 5.148592e+01
```

But, I couldn't get the inverse functions of *nlog2(n)* and *n!* (n factorial).
Therefore, I made a function to get an approximated values for n like below.
(this code is only for *nlog2(n)*.)

```
get_aprx_val <- function () {
    max_iter <- 100
    threshold <- 1.0e-07
    results <- rep( NA, length(time_units) )
    index <- 1

    for ( t_unit in time_units ) {
        x <- t_unit
        step <- .5 * t_unit

        for ( i in 1:max_iter ) {
            if ( x*log2(x) - t_unit >= threshold ) {
                x <- x - step
            }
            else if ( x*log2(x) - t_unit <= -threshold ) {
                x <- x + step
            }
            else {
                results[index] <- x
                break
            }
            step <- .5 * step
        }

        index <- index + 1
    }

    results
}
```

Although I've got result by doing above, like below,

```
[1] 6.274613e+04 2.801418e+06 1.333781e+08 2.755148e+09 7.187086e+10 7.976339e+11 6.861096e+13
```

but I'm not sure that I did them in the most efficient way.
Does anyone have better idea to help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what the table is supposed to contain.

Comment: Is your actual question how to calculate the inverse of f(n) = n * log2(n)?

Comment: @G.Bach Oh, I missed to explain about it.  For each table cells, they are supposed to contain <the larges size of n of a problem that can solved in time t>.  That is a good point! :)

Comment: @Roland Yes. My actual question is something like that, including the inverse of f(n) = n! only if it is possible to calculate them in analytic way.   But it's O.K. If I could get just each trivial solutions by some numerical methods.  I implemented one of a case as above (the last R code). But I don't know this is implemented in the most efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use numeric optimization, you could use `uniroot`:

```
sapply(time_units, 
       function(time) uniroot(function(n) n * log2(n) - time, c(1e-8, 1e20))$root)
#[1] 6.274613e+04 2.801418e+06 1.333781e+08 2.755148e+09 7.187086e+10 7.976339e+11 6.861096e+13
```

For a more efficient way you have to turn to maths.